# serverless & python: package is not being added to zip for deployment

Tags: python, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I'm adding `sqlalchemy` to my python project. `pip install ..., pip freeze...` all done.

`sqlalchemy` has been added to the requirements file.

After deployment I see an error about the package missing.

So, what am I missing?

Serverless.yml:

```
plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
  - serverless-wsgi

custom:
  wsgi:
    app: handler.app
    packRequirements: false
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux

package:
  exclude:
    - node_modules/**
    - venv/**
    - .terraform/**
    - .git/**


stacktrace


/var/task/wsgi_handler.py
49
raise Exception("Unable to import {}".format(config["app"]))
^ Exception Unable to import handler.app
/var/task/wsgi_handler.py
119
wsgi_app = import_app(config)
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>
219
<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>
783
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>
671
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>
975
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>
991
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>
1014
/var/lang/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py
127
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
/var/task/serverless_sdk/__init__.py
56
user_module = import_module(user_module_name)
/var/task/s_app.py
20
user_handler = serverless_sdk.get_user_handler('wsgi_handler.handler')
/var/task/s_app.py
25
raise e
/var/task/serverless_sdk/__init__.py
144
return user_handler(event, context)
/var/runtime/bootstrap.py
131
response = request_handler(event, lambda_context)
/var/task/s_app.py
25
raise e
/var/task/serverless_sdk/__init__.py
144
return user_handler(event, context)
/var/runtime/bootstrap.py
131
response = request_handler(event, lambda_context)
/var/task/s_app.py
25
raise e
/var/task/serverless_sdk/__init__.py
144
return user_handler(event, context)
/var/task/serverless_sdk/__init__.py
456
yield
```

Comment: can you share the error message in your post??

Comment: Share output of `SLS_DEBUG=* serverless package` for further details.